# The execution order and implementation details of Roslyn DiagnosticSuppressor API

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Recently I have stumbled upon the `DiagnosticSuppressor` API in Roslyn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticsuppressor.reportsuppressions?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0#microsoft-codeanalysis-diagnostics-diagnosticsuppressor-reportsuppressions(microsoft-codeanalysis-diagnostics-suppressionanalysiscontext)

I don't see a lot of information in the documentation, so I'm not sure in several things, that I wish to clarify.

- Can I use diagnostic suppressors to suppress my custom diagnostics?
  Is there an implementation example of such thing?
- Does diagnostic suppressors work both in IDE and standalone console tools (like analyzers) or they work only in IDE (like code fixes)?
- Can they be distributed and installed as Nuget packages?
- What is their execution order among compiler actions. Are they executed after the compilation end actions? I refer to the order described here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/analyzers/Analyzer%20Actions%20Semantics.md

> - For a given compilation, compilation start actions run first and compilation end actions run last.
> - For a given symbol, symbol start actions run before operation/syntax/symbol actions on a symbol and its members, and these operation/syntax/symbol actions run before the symbol end actions.
> - For a given operation block, operation block start actions run before operation node actions, and operation node actions run before the operation block end actions.
> - For a given code block, code block start actions run before syntax node actions, and syntax node actions run before code block end actions.
> - Otherwise, there are no ordering guarantees for action invocation.